# Diagram and child with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Please help me to make this diagram with TikZ. Here's the code I've been trying to write for 3 days. Help me, it's urgent for my report. Best regards!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps,pgfshade}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\tikzset{
  basic/.style  = {draw, text width=12em, drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
  root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
                   fill=cyan!30},
  level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=cyan!60,
                   text width=8em},
  level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=pink!60, text width=6.5em}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm},
  edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
  >=latex]

% root of the the initial tree, level 1
\node[root] {Indicateur \mbox{d'insécurité} alimentaire}
% The first level, as children of the initial tree
  child {node[level 2] (c1) {SCA}}
  child {node[level 2] (c2) {PDA}}
  child {node[level 2] (c3) {ISS}};

% The second level, relatively positioned nodes
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={level 3}]

\node [below of = c2, xshift=20pt, text width=6cm, draw](c21) {Cartographie de \mbox{l’insécurité} alimentaire};

\node [below of = c21, xshift=20pt, text width=4cm, draw](c22) {Analyse statistique bivariée};

\node [below of = c22, xshift=20pt, text width=4cm, draw](c23) {ACM suivie d'une CAH};

\node [below of = c23, xshift=20pt, text width=2cm, draw](c25) {GLOGIT2};

\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You seem to have made a good start with your diagram, what is stopping you from completing it?  Do you want the `xshift=20pt` option in the `level 3` nodes, it's shifting the successive levels to the right, which looks a bit odd

Comment: Hi Mrs. Bowen,
I was wrong with the option "xshift = 20pt". In fact, I wanted to reproduce exactly what is on the picture. Please help me, I'm just a debater. I removed this "xshift = 20pt" node. But I have not yet managed to reproduce exactly what is on the picture.

Comment: Just for info, to ping another user you have to write @ followed by the nickname of the user, for example @DaiBowen

Comment: @Clairant I get that you want to replicate the diagram but I don't really want to try and write all the code to do that for you. If there's a more abstract question you have about doing something in TikZ then that I'm keen to help with that. You've written (or obtained) some code which is posted, what's stopping you from adding more code to further improve your diagram by yourself? If you can explain that then I or somebody else will be more likely to want and be able to help with how to do what is holding you back.

Comment: Thanks @DaiBowen for your answer. Actually, I just wanted you to help me connect the arrows and add the ellipses to the right. Sorry to disturb you. Cordially !

Answer (score 3):

Not finished, but you can continue from following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
%\usepackage{positioning, pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps,pgfshade}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\tikzset{
  basic/.style  = {draw, text width=12em, drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
  root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
                   fill=cyan!30},
  level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin, align=center, fill=cyan!60,
                   text width=4em},
  level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=center, fill=pink!60, text width=6.5em}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=30mm},
  edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
  >=latex]

% root of the the initial tree, level 1
\node[root] (c) {Indicateur \mbox{d'insécurité} alimentaire}
% The first level, as children of the initial tree
  child {node[level 2] (c1) {SCA}}
  child {node[level 2] (c2) {PDA}}
  child {node[level 2] (c3) {ISS}};

% The second level, relatively positioned nodes
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={level 3}]

\node [below = of c2, text width=6cm, draw](c21) {Cartographie de \mbox{l’insécurité} alimentaire};

\node [below = of c21, text width=4cm, draw](c22) {Analyse statistique bivariée};

\node [below = of c22, text width=4cm, draw](c23) {ACM suivie d'une CAH};

\node [below = of c23, text width=2cm, draw](c24) {GLOGIT2};

\end{scope}

\foreach \i/\j in {c2/c21, c21/c22, c23/c24}
\draw[cyan, line width=1mm, >=latex, shorten >=.5mm, shorten <=1mm, ->] (\i)--(\j);

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={text width=4cm, ellipse, draw, align=center,
font=\sffamily, top color=white, bottom color=black!40}]

\node[right = 2cm of c] (d1) {Estimer le niveau d'insécurité alimentaire};

\node (d2) at (c21-|d1) {Où sont les ménages en insécurité alimentire?};

\path (c22)--coordinate (aux) (c23) ;

\node (d3) at (aux-|d1) {Caractériser les ménages eninsécurité alimentaire};

\node (d4) at (c24-|d1) {Analyser les déterminants de l'insécurité alimentire};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[line width=.5mm, >=latex, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm, ->]
\draw (c) -- (d1);
\draw (c21) -- (d2);
\draw (c22.east) --++(0:5mm)|- (d3);
\draw (c23.east) --++(0:5mm)|- (d3);
\draw (c24) -- (d4);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Waoh ! @lgnasi thank you very much. Best regards.